# ANTLR4 Runtime Jars

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, antlr, antlr4

When I add the following dependency to my Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
    <version>4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I get 7 dependencies in my module:

[image]

But how can I tell which jars are required at runtime?  Is it enough to distribute `org.antlr.antlr4-runtime:4.7` or do I need the other antlr dependencies?

Also, I have `antlr4-runtime:4.7` as well as `antlr-runtime:3.5.2`, which seems "wrong" but I don't know if both versions should be there or not.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this enough information?  http://www.antlr.org/api/maven-plugin/latest/dependencies.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I also use the antlr tool/IDEA plugin, so I'm not sure that antlr4-runtime would be sufficient during development time.

Comment: The antlr plugin for Intellij handles its own dependencies; it doesn't depend on the dependencies in your project.

Answer (score 3):

Your current dependency is on ANTLR 4 itself. If you want only the ANTLR 4 runtime, then you need to depend on artifact `antlr4-runtime`, not `antlr4`.

If this is sufficient depends on what your application does, but for normal applications that use an ANTLR 4 compiled grammar it should.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer.  SO won't let me accept it as an answer for another 5 minutes.  Go figure.